# Can I modify someone else's question to ask for a bit of additional information?

Tags: discussion

Consider [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/introductory-books-about-evolution).  I'd like to edit it, asking at the bottom for resources of evolution, in support of evolution, *written by Christians.*

I won't go into the depth of discussion but there is a small (but still significant) percentage of us Christians out there who do believe that Bible and evolution are congruent.

It has been a sad fact that for many centuries, church leadership hasn't embraced scientific discovery and truth when they have felt any new discovery might challenge their assumptions that are not fundamental to message and point of our religion.

In so much, I do believe in evolution and I do believe in the Bible.  I would be interested in reading on theory from such a perspective, written by a well educated source on the topic.

Should I modify the OP's question or post a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the key principles when editing other users' content is to *respect their original intent*.

With that in mind, I'm not sure that it would be an appropriate edit as you would be limiting the scope of answers to less than what the original poster intended.

I would reccomend that if you *solely* are looking for a Christian perspective you should create your own distinct question.  The community can then decide if it is constructive/on topic - it's not a call I'd like to make on my own!

Comment: I agree.  I guess my intent was to add an addendum, of sorts, to the end of the question, for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I would add your thoughts via a comment. The authors will receive a notification about comments but not necessarily edits. Typically, you can get the author to change their question to include (or exclude) your interpretation or followup questions to their question.